# Dealing with Unity's Global Menu and Overlay Scrollbars under Free Pascal/Lazarus

Tags: ubuntu, lazarus, fpc, ubuntu-unity

I've had some problems under the IDE that were fixed with [unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/) and disabling Global menu and the Overlay Scrollbars.

I've reported the problem in Lazarus' Mantis: [#0021465](http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=21465), [#0021467](http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=21467).
There is also this bug report talking a bit more about it: [#0019266](http://bugs.freepascal.org/bug_view_advanced_page.php?bug_id=19266)

Their solution was to use unsettings to turn off Global Menu and Overlay Scrollbars.

I've had a quick search about the problem and there's an open bug report at Launchpad: [overlay scrolling is broken in lazarus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-scrollbar/+bug/847964).

So, is the problem related to "lib overlay scrollbar"?
If it is, is there a solution via code, to avoid turning off both the Global Menu and Overlay Scrollbars?
If *NOT*, is there anyone taking notice and fixing the issue?

Many thanks,
Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Zeljan Rikalo (cf. mantis [0020520](http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=20520)) this issue is not fixable from lazarus itself. Instead you can export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 or use libc.putenv() (man putenv) and add LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 to your application.